# SQL Server Migration from 2008 R2 to 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have migrated the database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014 with the help of backup/restore method. Now my database in SQL Server 2014 and has compatibility level 100, I didn't change it to 120.

If I change it to 120, will it flush all the query plans? As in SQL Server 2014, Microsoft has rewritten the cardinality estimator. So will it flush the old plan and regenerate the plan according to new cardinality estimator? Can anyone explain this or point to the reference where I can understand it clearly?

Comment: Start here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/careful-testing-the-2014-cardinality-estimator-with-trace-flags/

Comment: thnks for the link...as gone through the blog...in comment section i seen this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044519/fix-query-performance-issues-when-new-cardinality-estimator-is-enabled which says we have to update it to SP1 to get rid of the new cardinality issues...this will fix it right?

Comment: Query plans are flushed every time the server is restarted, regardless of compatibility level. Switching to a new server will for sure start with its cache empty.